# GitHub add external library for maven project

Tags: java, maven, github

I want to build my project to use maven, but I have an external library in dependencies. I found an info about how to do it.
http://cemerick.com/2010/08/24/hosting-maven-repos-on-github/#fn2
It works perfect for libraries which are built in maven. I checked it. :) But when I started to do it I encountered with problems. All libraries should have strict structures like meta-info.pom and so on. I don't know how to generate this files for external libraries.
Could you possibly help me with it?
Yours faithfully.

Comment: These files are generated and maintained by Maven repository managers like Nexus. Why do you need them? As long as you don't want to host snapshot revisions you shouldn't need them.

Comment: Well. Actually We have an e-commercial product which offers to make an extensions. Customers can make some scripts with core library from this app. I'd like to make this task with use maven artifact and I'd like to make common repository where I will put this core library. Is it possible to make without Nexus?

Comment: It's possible, but I wouldn't recommend this approach. Would be far simpler to either run an instance of Nexus (or Artifactory, or Archiva) or embed one of the open source repository managers within your product. This sounds interesting, I think you should restructure your question with more details of your intentions.

Comment: Actually, "deploying" your library to a source control host is an efficient way to quickly publish your libraries to the outside world. See http://code.google.com/p/maven-svn-wagon/wiki/MavenRepositoryInsideGoogleCode

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very commonly done. Many OSS libraries that are not in "Maven Central" are available as Maven repositories hosted on Google Code.

The way you do this is by configuring the "SCM Wagon" for your `<distributionManagement>` configuration. If you manually build the directory structure, it's not enough. You should use the approach outlined in the linked blog post and here: [Maevn Wagon SCM](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-scm/usage.html)

One of the sections is entitled "Deploying your Maven site to GitHub's gh-pages."  I suspect this is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Hello. I have read this manual, but I have not got the success. Actually I think to write a step-by-step manual what I have done.